# Signal Sigabrat when pushing button in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Hi I have an error when I press my button in one page to connect to another view

would you please help me
Thanks in advance!

**Here is my code**

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
NSLog(@"button %u -- frame: %@", button.tag, NSStringFromCGRect(button.frame));
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WeekView" sender:self];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"WeekView"]){

    [segue.destinationViewController setTitle:@"WeekView"];
    }}
```

**this error in this line**

```
with debugging = Signal Sigabrat start from here

 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WeekView" sender:self];
```

I also identify WeekView in Segue and also use shipt+command+K to clean but still error

Comment: you do have created a segue in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your destinationviewcontroller before you can change properties:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"WeekView"]){

SecondViewController*second=segue.destinationViewController;   //You´re missing this line.

second.title=@"WeekView";    // now you can do stuff on your destinationViewController



    }}
```

I hope it fixes it.